EF Core 8: execute a query and map it to a non-entity
It seems like EF Core 8 is supposed to allow raw SQL queries for unmapped types, but I'm not sure on how to use it with complex types.
For instance, suppose you have the following:
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public B B { get; set; }

    // other properties
}

public class B 
{
    public int IdB { get; set; }
    public int Description { get; set; }
}

And the SQL looks like this:
SELECT 
    ..., 
    SomeColumn as IdB, 
    SomeDescription as Description,
    ...
FROM
    Summary

where IdB and Description should be used to create an instance of B for each row.
I've tried getting away with this:
List<dynamic> toConvert = await _dbContext.Database.SqlQueryRaw<dynamic>(sql, parameters)
                                                              .ToListAsync( );

Which obviously doesn't work. Is there a way for me to map this query to the expected type without having to resort to low level commands and data readers?
Thanks.

Doesn't List<B> list = await dbContext.Database.SqlQueryRaw<B>(sql, parameters).ToListAsync() work or not?

I'm not even sure why you expect EF to be capable of that. It would have to infer a depth-aware column mapping on the fly. Too much room for ambiguities and error.

Wondering if there's  something like NHibernate's CreateSqlQuery where you can write  something like_session.CreateSqlQuery(sql).Future().ToList().Select( r => new A(..., new B(i[1], i[2])? And if not, then maybe dapper is the way to go...

Using EF, you'll always need a class to capture the flat data. Then, of course, you can project into whatever you like.

No, at the moment this does not seem to be supported by EF. To use unmapped types you need to have a flat type otherwise you will get something like the following error (source code):

Navigations are not supported when using 'SqlQuery". Either include this type in the model and use 'FromSql' for the query, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute.

EF internally uses quite limited subset of conventions for this type of mapping, for example removing things like owned types and many more.
Options:

Create an intermediate type to contain the flattened version of the result and map it to destination one.

Use Dapper for this particular query, AFAIK it supports such type of mapping.

Look into mapping this type for example in some kind of keyless entity type maybe combined with complex type (TBH I'm a bit surprised that they are not supported in this case, possibly it would be worth to request support for it)


